# Docker build fails on GitHub Actions

Tags: docker, containers, github-actions

I'm getting an error when I run a Docker build and push script through GitHub Actions. This is the error:

```
# ------
Dockerfile:48
# --------------------
46 |     RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs
47 |     
48 | >>> COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
49 |     
50 |     # Set the correct permission for prerender cache
# --------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref x-x-x-x-x::x: "/app/public": not found
```

I think it might have to do with the files being built on the GH server and the script can't find the right context. Here's my workflow file:

```yaml
name: Docker Image CI for GHCR

on: push

jobs:
build_and_publish:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
uses: actions/checkout@v4
name: Build and push the image
run: |
docker login --username x --password ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }} ghcr.io
docker build . --tag ghcr.io/x/x
docker push ghcr.io/x/x:latest
```

This Dockerfile is taken straight from Next.js docs:

```dockerfile
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:18-alpine AS base

Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
fi


Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN \
if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build; \
elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build; \
elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build; \
else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
fi

Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
set hostname to localhost
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

server.js is created by next build from the standalone output
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/output
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

I tried adding context to the build and push but got syntax errors.

Comment: Did you verify that the `public` directory exists in the builder stage??